# Quorum transaction not mined and no address

Tags: transactions, addresses, quorum, pending-transactions

I am running a private `Quorum` chain consisting of 3 nodes with `raft` consensus. When I deploy a contract to the chain via `web3` I get returned a hash and can then look up the transaction with the local geth console (`geth attach qdata/geth.ipc`) and check its status with `eth.getTransaction(hash)`, so I get this:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xc58a28d310c76e8298fa086381e6f2da9f046c07",
  gas: 4700000,
  gasPrice: 0,
  hash: "0x75bf6fc10400fa493851b8105973e9b5aab2955dc5d87d217f13ed9562ccafbd",
  input: "0xc2f448268ee5019782beeaee884bc92112187a16af7b23df948fd0f867ecb2f41f34f34e477e2ddd53c74ef20fc48b0ebcda0a003f991f9c6e1a4bedfc65288d",
  nonce: 0,
  r: "0x3cd6c0a90a9b2367d6d47f081ad8509ea374f4db54bbf51eb9ace8360e50bc7a",
  s: "0x6d6cabc76a0d7774ada6ba753d06be0400353a5d3d42d85c92c4db7b8ad2f7bd",
  to: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x26",
  value: 0
}
```

But there is no address! So why is the transaction still not mined?

**EDIT:**
Here is the code I used to deploy the contract:

```
const Web3 = require('web3-quorum');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://..SERVER_ADDRESS..:22000'));

var abiArray = [{...ABI...}];
var simpleContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);
var bytecode = "0x6080604052348...";
const account = '0xc58a28d310c76...';

var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
const contractData = {
    from: account,
    data: bytecode,
    gas: 0x47b760,
    privateFor: ["oUEMYuV2DOlgk88JxKx..."],
    nonce: '0x' + nonce
};

//contract instance
const contractInstance = simpleContract.new(123, contractData, function(e, contract) {
    if (e) {
        console.log("err creating contract", e);
    } else {
        if (!contract.address) {
            console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
            console.log(contract);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share the code that sent the transaction ? is it inside a loop ? how much did the transaction stay in pending ?

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime sure, I edited my question. Actually the pending tx is not the matter, its more about why there is no contract address after deployment and `eth.getTransaction`.

Comment: I think you should look at this. https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/master/docs/api.md#returns
thought it might look the same, quorum has some key differences with the base ethereum, I think this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This could be maybe due to

1. The nodes arent synced, so you could restart the whole setup and check do the transactions.
2. Try to get the confirmations on the transactions done in the console.This code may help you

```
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction("0x" + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'), (_err, _res) => {
        if(_err){
            console.error("ERROR: ", _err);
        } else {
            console.log("success: ", _res);
        }
    }).on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
        console.log('=> confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber);
    })
    .on('transactionHash', hash => {       
       res.status(200).json({ Message : "success", Body : hash})
    })
    .on('receipt', receipt => {
        console.log('=> reciept');
        console.log(receipt);
    })
    .on('error', console.error);

});
```